# Kali Linux - XFCE4 'Trash Can' & 'Home' Folder Not Opening

Tags: linux, kali-linux

i am on my kali linux latest version on the time i am making this post, so i am having a error that whenever i am trying to open the "HOME" Folder on my desktop or the "Trash Can" on my desktop it is showing me a error which says:

> The folder could not be opened
>
> Failed to execute child process "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/exo-2/exo-helper-2"
> (no such file or directory)

i have a full recorded video on my gdrive which you can see from [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C8qLiKnDnknuTXBArlAzejfts2bRnk7s/view?usp=sharing)

please see the problem and tell me how can i fix it, & why it occured

Thanks

Comment: It looks like the default program your desktop environment uses to open files is no longer installed.  In the Applications context menu, try opening it with `thunar` (xfce4's default file browser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `libexo-2-0`:

```
sudo apt install libexo-2-0
```

Comment: Thanks Bro, It Worked!

Answer (score 1):

Some times `sudo apt install libexo-2-0` shows a message  already installed

check whether  what is the application inode/directory using

```
xdg-mime query default inode/directory                                127 ⨯
code.desktop
```

if it is something like this; changed to thunar.desktop will
solve this problem

```
xdg-mime default thunar.desktop inode/directory
```

Comment: This worked for me.  Thanks